# How to synchronize two tables in SSIS

Tags: sql, database, ssis

I have a scenario where i need to synchronize two tables in SSIS

`Table A` is in DATABASE A and `TABLE B` is in DATABASE B. Both tables have same schema. I need to have a SSIS package that Synchronize TABLE A with TABLE B in Such a way That

`1. It inserts all the records That Exist in Table A into Table B`

AND

```
2. Update TABLE B if Same "Key" exsit in Both but Updated records in Table A
```

For Example    Table A and B both Contains Key = 123 both Few Columns in Table A has been Updated.

I am thinking about using Merge Joins but that helps with only insertion of New records. How i can manage to implement UPDATE thing as well

Comment: Wouldn't this task be better suited to something like SQL Server functionality like mirroring/log shipping/replication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.It inserts all the records That Exist in Table A into Table B
```

Use a [lookup transformation](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2010/02/09/ssis-snack-configuring-an-ssis-2005-lookup-transformation-for-a-left-outer-join.aspx) .Source will be `Table A` and Lookup will be `Table B` .Map the common columns in both the table and select those columns which you need for insertion.After lookup use `OLEDB destination` and the map the columns coming from the lookup and insert it into `Table B`

```
2.Update TABLE B if Same "Key" exsit in Both but Updated records in Table A
```

Same logic as above .Use lookup and instead of `OLEDB Destination` use `OLEDB Command` and then write the update sql .

```
Update TableB
Set col1=?,col2=?....
```

In the column mapping map the columns coming out of the `lookup`

Check out this article
[Checking to see if a record exists and if so update else insert](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/09/12/SSIS_3A00_-Checking-if-a-row-exists-and-if-it-does_2C00_-has-it-changed.aspx)

Using Merge :

```
MERGE TableB b
USING TableA a
ON b.Key = a.Key
WHEN MATCHED AND b.Col1<>a.Col1 THEN
UPDATE
SET b.Col1 =  a.Col1 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (Col1, Col2, col3)
VALUES (a.Col1, a.Col2,a.Col3);
```

You can execute the Merge SQL in `Execute SQL Task` in `Control Flow`

Update : `The Lookup transformation tries to perform an equi-join between values in the transformation input and values in the reference dataset.`

You can just need to  have one Data Flow Task .

Diagram

[image]

When the target table data does not have a matching value in the source table then lookup will redirect the target  rows to the oledb destination which inserts the Data into source table( `Lookup No Match Output`)

When the target table rows matches for the business key with the source table then matched rows will be sent to the `Oledb Command` and using the Update SQL ,the all the target rows from the lookup will be updated in the source table .

This is just an overview .There is a problem with the above design as when the rows matches irrespective of any change in the columns the source table will be updated .So kindly refer the above article or try for search for SCD component  in ssis

```
Update 2:

MERGE TableB b
USING TableA a
ON b.Key = a.Key
WHEN MATCHED  THEN
UPDATE
SET b.Col1 =  a.Col1 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND a.IsReady=1 THEN  --isReady bit data type
INSERT (Col1, Col2, col3)
VALUES (a.Col1, a.Col2,a.Col3);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate Lookup transformation in detail? Do i need to have two separate Data Flow Tasks to accomplolish INSERT and UPDATE separately.

Comment: I am going with Merge SQL and will execuate it within ExecuteSQL task. Now my Question is , I want to Merge them on Some Condition like where Table A has an addtion Column IsReady and if it's set to True then Merge All Records in Table A where IsReady is True with Table B. Is it possible to Add such Condition in Merge SQL or i need a Temp Table to move All Records from Table A where IsReady is True and then Merge That Temp Table With Table B

Comment: One Last thing , I forgot to mention my Table A and Table B are in Two Separate Databases but on the same Server. Your Solution works fine in SQL Server Management STudio but when i try it in ExecuteSQL task it does not. It's not throwing any Error but it goes yellow and never turns Green or Red. How i can solve this Issue. I believe ExcuteSQL runs Query againt One Database Only

Comment: If tables are on the same server  then you need to reference the table using database names .Example database..tableName or database.schema.tableName

Comment: That works in Query Analyzer but does not work in ExecuteSQL task

Comment: Try to check with sql profiler and see what query is being executed in sql server when u execute the SSIS pkg