# How to migrate Azure SQL Database to another Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

I have one SQLServer in Azure portal and in that server has 2 SQL Databases TestDB1 and TestDB2 is copy of TestDB1. But we used TestDB2 for testing and now it has more data compared to TestDB1. I want to migrate only unavailable data from TestDB2 to TestDB1 as both are having same DB schema. How to do it?

Comment: does this answer your question [How to: Compare and Synchronize the Data of Two Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-compare-and-synchronize-the-data-of-two-databases?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: It sounds like the database are in the same instance, if that is the case then you can possibly use the merge syntax to compare the data, if it doesnt matche then insert/update the rows that dont match. Could you update your question with an example of the date. e.g. two tables and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, I've tested it locally and it does merge in test data from a sperate database, full example shown

[image]

```
USE [Playground2] -- Swap for your database name

CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50), 
    [Age] INT, 

)

INSERT INTO MyTable([Name], [Age])
VALUES('Andrew', '28'),
('Robert', '38'),
('James', '40'),
('Robin', '40'), 
('Peter', '56'), -- second database has this extra data
('Steve', '22') -- second database has this extra data

GO

USE [Playground] -- Swap for your database name

CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50), 
    [Age] INT, 

)

INSERT INTO MyTable([Name], [Age])
VALUES('Andrew', '28'),
('Robert', '38'),
('James', '40'),
('Robin', '40') 

GO

-- Check that the tables have slightly different data
SELECT * FROM Playground.dbo.MyTable
SELECT * FROM Playground2.dbo.MyTable

BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable ON

    MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable AS TGT
    USING [Playground2].dbo.MyTable AS SRC -- Note that we point to the other database here seeing as it is on the same SQL instance
        ON  TGT.Id = SRC.Id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET 
        TGT.[Name] = SRC.[Name],
        TGT.[Age] = SRC.[Age]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT(Id, [Name], [Age])
        VALUES(SRC.Id, SRC.[Name], SRC.[Age])
    OUTPUT $action AS [Action],
        deleted.[Name] AS OldName, 
        inserted.[Name] AS [NewName],
        deleted.[Age] AS OldCountry, 
        inserted.[Age] AS NewCountry;

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable OFF

    SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable
        
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION -- Change to COMMIT TRANSACTION when you are happy with  the results

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Rolling back changes, there was an error!!' 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @Msg NVARCHAR(MAX)  
    SELECT @Msg=ERROR_MESSAGE() 
    RAISERROR('Error Occured: %s', 20, 101,@msg) WITH LOG
END CATCH
```

But there also will be tools to do this, but this could be one answer, cheers

Comment: Hi Andrew,

Thank you for your help. I am looking Database merge not single table. My DB has more than 45+ tables. I can't sit and do one by one.

Comment: ok, maybe you need to look at SSIS (SQL Server integration Services) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911637/how-to-synchronize-two-tables-in-ssis
I personally think its a bit of a learning curve so not used it much. (clunkey stuff)